# What's the username parameter used for?

Tags: spotipy

I'm trying to authenticate with spotipy using Authorization Code Flow like this:

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,redirect_uri=redirect_url)
```

When I assign any string to "username", I'm asked to authenticate the request in a browser which is popping up; everything works fine.

When I set a different string to "username" before running my code a second time, the authentication is done against the previously authenticated username (which is still authenticated in the browser session); just as if the value of "username" is not taken into account at all.

Also, I seem to be able to set any arbitrary value to "username" like "pipapo"; when I login to my Spotify account (which isn't "pipapo", obviously) this one is authenticated and methods like `current_user_saved_tracks()` do get the resources of the account authenticated instead of "pipapo".

Anyways: The access_token and refresh_token are saved to the cachefile `.cache-pipapo`; thus saving the credentials of the "who-ever-logged-into-the-browser" to the file named after the "wrong" account.

So: What is this parameter good for then, if ultimately the user's interactive selections are responsible for what the code is doing? And why is this even a required parameter if more or less not utilized in the auth process?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at `spotipy/util.py` myself, how `def prompt_for_user_token(...)` is designed and what parameter "username" is used for; indeed, it is used for defining the caching file name only to hand it over to `oauth2.SpotifyOAuth()` like so:

```
cache_path=".cache-" + username
```

So, you can use any value here; it does not need to be the correct username, necessarily.